# map function in Swift converting String to Int?

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
let digitNames = [
    0: "Zero", 1: "One", 2: "Two",   3: "Three", 4: "Four",
    5: "Five", 6: "Six", 7: "Seven", 8: "Eight", 9: "Nine"
]
let numbers = [16, 58, 510]

let strings = numbers.map {
    (var number) -> String in
    var output = ""
    while number > 0 {
        output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
        number /= 10
    }
    return output
}
// strings is inferred to be of type [String]
// its value is ["OneSix", "FiveEight", "FiveOneZero"]
```

I was hoping if there is anyone that could explain how this code works (it is taken from apple's developer page for swift under "closures). I'm not too sure especially what the code in the "while" loop means :/ how exactly is the number converted to string?

Comment: It's just maths. `%` is the modulo operator, `/=` divides the left-hand-side by the right-hand-side. From that, it's obvious that this code extracts the individual digits of `number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` function is Higher Order Level function and it is used to do some operation on single elements of `array` and return a transformed array generated after your operations.

`numbers.map` will traverse each element of array and transform the elements by doing some operation and returned a transformed array .

```
output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output
```

1) for first element in array `16` in first iteration of while loop `number % 10` will return 6 as a reminder of 16 after dividing by `10` so  `digitName[6]` will assign `output` to `Six`

```
let strings = numbers.map {
    (var number) -> String in
    var output = ""
    while number > 0 {
        output = digitNames[number % 10]! + output  //16 
        number /= 10
    }
    return output
}
```

2) It divides `number` by 10 and which will give 1 now number will be `1`

3) `while number > 0 {` checks if number is greater than 0 yes it is `1`

4) Again iterate now this time `digitNames[number % 10]!` return `One` and by appending previous output it will become `One` append `output`(which is Six).So `OneSix`

Your first element become `OneSix`.This will done for each element and after all elements `map` return `String` array.So finally `String` become

`["OneSix", "FiveEight", "FiveOneZero"]`